# Using a lambda to generically create an arbitrary class wrapper around some object of type T

Tags: c++, c++17, template, lambda, wrapper

While experimenting with some of C++'s language features, I was able to successfully design an invokable nameless function call through the use of a lambda that generically creates an arbitrary class wrapper that returns a class object without having to have a direct implementation of that class within its own seperate translation unit. The wrapper class itself is still contained within a translation unit, as it is declared and defined within the scope of the lambda. This lambda then returns that type through the use of template type deduction.

In my case, I have created a Wrapper class around a type `T` object in that it stores a pointer to that object and its constructor and destructor respectively calls new and delete on that pointer. The members are private and only accessible via the class's public interface, and they are declared as `const` non-modifiable meaning that the use of calling these methods will not change the state of the class object that is generated. To better illustrate this, here is what my source code looks like:

**some.h**

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

template<typename T>
auto create_dynamic_wrapper = [&](const std::string_view name, T value) {
    class DynamicWrapper {
    public:
        DynamicWrapper() = default;

        DynamicWrapper(const std::string_view name_in, T value) : name_{ name_in } {
            this->pData_ = new T{ value };
        }

        ~DynamicWrapper() {
            if (nullptr != this->pData_) {
                delete this->pData_;
                this->pData_ = nullptr;
            }
        }

        // define copy constructor and assignment operator here
        // wrt how you want this wrapper class to behave in order
        // to preserve the rule of 3 or 5. Meaning, do you want
        // to allow this class object to be copyable or not... 

        auto value() const { return *(this->pData_); }
        auto ptr() const { return this->pData_; }
        auto name() const { return this->name_; }
    private:
        T* pData_ = nullptr;
        const std::string name_;
    };
    return DynamicWrapper(name, value);
};
```

The driving program

**main**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "some.h"

int main() {
    auto C = create_dynamic_wrapper<int>("Foo", 7);
    std::cout << C.name() << '\n';
    std::cout << C.ptr() << '\n';
    std::cout << C.value() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(C).name() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this on my machine I get the following output:

**Output**

```
Foo
00000000006857F0
7
class `public: __cdecl <lambda_986b701ab3be1e8cd3d0d2d875c96c7d>::operator()(class std::basic_string_view<char,struct st
d::char_traits<char> >,int)const __ptr64'::`2'::DynamicWrapper
```

The second line will vary as this is using dynamic heap memory allocation.
The fourth line will vary depending on the compiler, os, and other factors due to naming conventions, name mangling, symbol generation, etc...

Now onto my questions and concerns...

---

- I don't know if this type of code structure/generation has a specific
  idiomatic name. If so, what would this Idiom be called?
- Is this considered a Well-Defined Program?
- What are the implications of using this kind of structure:

  - Will this invoke any kind of UB?
  - Does this have the potential to introduce memory leaks, invalid or dangling pointers, or references?
  - Would this be considered thread and exception-safe?
- Explain to me what you believe are the pros and cons of using this kind of code generation?
- Without having to use `smart-pointers` is there anything else that I would need to be aware of when it comes to the use of dynamic memory while using new and delete within a self-contained object defined within this context?
- What are the side effects of using this kind of structure?
- What can I or do I need to do to improve this code snippet to make it a well-defined codebase that doesn't introduce any potential UB?
- What would be the potential exploits of using this type of implementation?
- If all of the necessary precautions are taken to eliminate any code smells... would this kind of code structure be a useful tool in any kind of production code?

---

*-Note to the Reader-*

There is something to be said about this code structure that I find interesting. The lambda itself internally and locally declares and defines a class object named `DynamicWrapper<T>` where this class is defined and declared within the scope of this lambda and through the use of `auto type deduction` it returns an instantiated class instance of that type.

Then within some translation unit that calls and invokes this lambda and through the use of the `auto` specifier, the named object that is returned into the user's declared `auto variable` is in fact a `DynamicWrapper<T>` instance even though no such class declaration or definition exists outside of that invoked lambda. I find this to have a very interesting set of properties and behavior in regards to its overall design pattern and implementation.

Comment: One thing missing from this review - what do you use it *for*?

Comment: To Close-vote reviewers - this turns out to be hypothetical/example code, not finished real code ready for review - see the comments to [my answer](/a/255687/75307).

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Given that you would always have a `value`, what is the justification for `pData` to be a pointer?

Comment: @screwnut... It's hard to put in exact words... I'm not exactly interested in the details of the "wrapper class itself". It's the outer construct, the design pattern of using Lambda's to generically generate classes where they are only declared and defined within the Lambda's implementation body... if that makes more sense... I was only using a vague "wrapper class" to illustrate the use of the outer lambda that is generating that class, and the fact that the `auto` variable within some other translation unit is an instantiation of that contained class.

Comment: @screwnut There are different Idioms in C++ in which I have used such as SFINAE, CRTP, Factory, Polymorphism, etc... I don't know if this kind of design pattern has an "idiomatic name", if it doesn't I don't know it otherwise I would use that within the question itself...

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know if this type of code structure/generation has a specific idiomatic name. If so, what would this Idiom be called?

Not sure myself.

> Is this considered a Well-Defined Program?

Looks good to me.

> What are the implications of using this kind of structure:
>
> - Will this invoke any kind of UB?

Looks well formed.

> - Does this have the potential to introduce memory leaks, invalid or dangling pointers, or references?

In the general case no.
In this specific case: You did not implement the rule of three/five and you are managing a dynamically created resource inside the class. So there is definitely the possibility for resource mishandling.

> Would this be considered thread and exception-safe?

Nothing is thread safe unless you explicitly make it so (apart from the things that are specifically designed for threading: `atomic`, `mutex`, `condition_variable` etc...).

Exception safe. Yes as long as the rule of three issue is solved.

> Explain to me what you believe are the pros and cons of using this kind of code generation?

Not sure you need a lambda to do this:
The standard pattern is to use a `make_X` function. See: `make_pair()`.

```
template<typename T>
class DynamicWrapper {
public:
    DynamicWrapper() = default;

    DynamicWrapper(const std::string_view name_in, T value) : name_{ name_in } {
        this->pData_ = new T{ value };
    }

    ~DynamicWrapper() {
        if (nullptr != this->pData_) {
            delete this->pData_;
            this->pData_ = nullptr;
        }
    }

    auto value() const { return *(this->pData_); }
    auto ptr() const { return this->pData_; }
    auto name() const { return this->name_; }
private:
    T* pData_ = nullptr;
    const std::string name_;
};

template<typename T>
DynamicWrapper<T> make_DynamicWrapper(std::string_view name_in, T&& value)
{
    return DynamicWrapper<T>(std::move(name_in), std::forward<T>(value));
}

int main()
{
    auto C = make_DynamicWrapper("Foo", 7);
}
```

> Without having to use smart-pointers is there anything else that I would need to be aware of when it comes to the use of dynamic memory while using new and delete within a self-contained object defined within this context?

Obey the rule of three/five.

> What are the side effects of using this kind of structure?

Nothing really.

> What can I or do I need to do to improve this code snippet to make it a well-defined codebase that doesn't introduce any potential UB?

Looks good.

> What would be the potential exploits of using this type of implementation?

Not sure what that means.

> If all of the necessary precautions are taken to eliminate any code smells...

No smells.

> would this kind of code structure be a useful tool in any kind of production code?

Sure is.

---

A thing to note is that lambda expressions are just short hand notation for writing functors. So we could rewrite your lambda as follows (which shows what is effectively happening in the compiler).

```
template<typename T>
struct Lambda_986b701ab3be1e8cd3d0d2d875c96c7d
{
    class DynamicWrapper {
    public:
        DynamicWrapper() = default;

        DynamicWrapper(const std::string_view name_in, T value) : name_{ name_in } {
            this->pData_ = new T{ value };
        }

        ~DynamicWrapper() {
            if (nullptr != this->pData_) {
                delete this->pData_;
                this->pData_ = nullptr;
            }
        }

        // define copy constructor and assignment operator here
        // wrt how you want this wrapper class to behave in order
        // to preserve the rule of 3 or 5. Meaning, do you want
        // to allow this class object to be copyable or not... 

        auto value() const { return *(this->pData_); }
        auto ptr() const { return this->pData_; }
        auto name() const { return this->name_; }
    private:
        T* pData_ = nullptr;
        const std::string name_;
    };

    DynamicWrapper operator()(const std::string_view name, T value) const
    {
        return DynamicWrapper(name, value);
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto c = Lambda_986b701ab3be1e8cd3d0d2d875c96c7d<int>{}("Fun", 7);
}
```

Comment: About the rule of 3 or 5... I did not include the `copy constructor` nor the `assignment operator` in that they should be "self-explanatory" or well understood and thought feel that they are in a sense irrelevant to the actual implementation of its design. Other than that, you're answer is very straightforward, concise, and to the point!

Comment: Now, since the above class generation handles its memory allocation internally, and the fact that it can not be modified from outside of its class, would it be safe to say that the default copy constructor and assignment operator would be viable within this context? I haven't decided if the generated wrapper object itself should be copyable or not... that's another reason for their direct omission. I guess I could have commented them out with a description explaining their omissions.

Comment: I also know that I could have done this with a `class template` and a `function`. However, I combined the two into a single lambda expression just to explore some of the features and properties of lambdas within modern C++.

Comment: I added a comment to the class in regards to its copy constructor and assignment operator to reflect your statement about the rule of 3 or 5 so that future readers of this Q/A can see the reasoning for their explicit omission. The idea of leaving the comments is to state that they should be defined there, but that they are implementation-defined as to the designer's intended use of this class, making the class either copyable or non-copyable.

Comment: “make” functions are kinda going the way of the dodo as of C++17; `make_pair()` is already obsolete. I’d say forget the lambda *and* the make function, and just use template parameter deduction (with an appropriate deduction guide if necessary): `auto c = DynamicWrapper{"foo", 7};`.

Comment: @indi Can't really argue with that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's not clear at all what this is for, that's any different to `std::pair<T, std::string>`.  What's the motivation?

---

This won't work in C++20:

```
255676.cpp:5:32: error: non-local lambda expression cannot have a capture-default
    5 | auto create_dynamic_wrapper = [&](const std::string_view name, T value) {
      |                                ^
```

We don't seem to need a default capture, so we could just use `[]` instead - but why not just write a function?

Actually, I've just checked and it's not legal in C++17 either, so the code is invalid as presented.

---

> ```
>     DynamicWrapper() = default;
> ```

What's this default constructor for?  We never use it.

---

> ```
>     DynamicWrapper(const std::string_view name_in, T value) : name_{ name_in } {
>         this->pData_ = new T{ value };
>     }
> ```

Why are you assigning to `pData` rather than simply initialising it as you do `name`?  Also, making `name_in` a const parameter forces us to copy it into `name`, rather than being able to move it.  I'd write:

```
    DynamicWrapper(std::string name, T value)
        : pData_{new T{std::move(value)}},
          name_{std::move(name)}
    {
    }
```

---

> ```
>     ~DynamicWrapper() {
>         if (nullptr != this->pData_) {
>             delete this->pData_;
>             this->pData_ = nullptr;
>         }
>     }
> ```

There's a lot of clutter here.  First, we can ditch all the `this->` rubbish that only serves to make the code less readable.  Why are we comparing against a null pointer?  If `pData_` is null, then there's no need for the test because the `delete` will do nothing anyway.  And that's a dead assignment to `pData_`, because the object is going out of scope.  That can all be replaced with a much simpler destructor:

```
    ~DynamicWrapper() {
        delete pData_;
    }
```

However, I think we should reconsider the type of `pData_`.  As `g++ -Weffc++` warns us, we have a pointer data member but no copy-constructor and no copy-assignment operator, making this a dangerous class to use.

If we replace `pData_` with a smart pointer, then the compiler-generated (or compiler-deleted) constructor, destructor and assignment will just do the Right Thing (that's the Rule of Zero).

Here's a simpler version of the same thing:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
auto create_dynamic_wrapper(std::string name, T value)
{
    class DynamicWrapper {
    public:
        DynamicWrapper(std::string name, T value)
            : value_{new T{std::move(value)}},
              name_{std::move(name)}
        {
        }

        auto value() const { return *value_; }
        auto const& ptr() const { return value_; }
        auto name() const { return name_; }
    private:
        const std::shared_ptr<T> value_;
        const std::string name_;
    };
    return DynamicWrapper(std::move(name), std::move(value));
}
```

I still don't see the point, though.

Comment: I know I could have just written a function. That wasn't the point of my code design. It was the fact that I was able to create a class that exists only in the scope of a lambda via its declaration and definition. Then when the lambda is invoked in some translation unit, the contained class type is still instantiated and returned via auto. It's more about the `pattern` and its behavior. I explicitly stated I wasn't concerned with `smart_pointers` as I was working internally and directly with `new` and `delete`. I tagged C++17, not C++20. I was only using a wrapper object as an illustration.

Comment: In Psudeo Code and Simply put: `auto obj = [](params...){ class Obj { pubic: members; } Obj o(params...); return o;};` then `obj` is of type `Obj`... This is the pattern that I am concerned with. Not how to take this and make a function out of it! It's the idea to be able to use a lambda to create an instance of a class externally from a class that it declares and defines internally. The only place that the class exists is within that lambda obj... and not within the file's global namespace... at least until you invoke the lambda.

Comment: Yes, I saw the C++17 tag, and initially thought I was warning about something you'd done that was incompatible with C++20.  Then I found it's already broken in C++17.  I still don't see why you find a named lambda better than an ordinary function - what's the advantage?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and it worked for me without any issues

Comment: "*I was only using a wrapper object as an illustration*" makes it sound like this isn't [**actual code from a real project**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Can you tell us what you're using this for?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm working on a bigger project where I might be auto-generating a bunch of classes that all share a similar pattern. I was thinking of using templated lambdas to achieve this... So I wanted to know more about the design pattern itself. The `wrapper` class was just a special use case to illustrate the point of the design and use of invoking the lambda to create a class instance through auto type deduction.

Comment: I know you "*explicitly stated I wasn't concerned with smart_pointers*", but IMO you should be - that's an important tool to creating maintainable code.  Otherwise you'd shoot yourself in the foot the first time you passed one of these objects by value.  If you're not interested in critique of all aspects of your code, then Code Review is probably the wrong place to be.

Comment: I know all about using smart pointers. My focus wasn't on them... I was doing it the old fashion C way, just to make the code easier to read, just to illustrate that the class was using dynamic memory instead of local stack memory, nothing more. Within my real codebase, of course, I'd be using smart pointers, except in specific special cases.

Comment: You know about smart pointers *and still chose not to use one*?  Are you sure that this is your **real, finished code**?  Now you're talking about your "*real codebase*" I'm convinced that I've wasted my valuable time on an off-topic question that's hypothetical/example code.  Please don't do that to us again.

Comment: I made an edit to the bottom of the question in how I would be using this design pattern within my code. That's what I'm focusing on. My codebase is quite large and I'm working with a lot of components and I'm using Vulkan as my rendering API. I want to know about the `design pattern` itself. The idea of using `lambdas` to create class instances where those lambdas generates (declares & defines) the classes...

Comment: @FrancisCugler Visual Studio does not always follow the standards. If you want the code to port to non-windows systems you need to stick to the standards.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I'm not targeting any platform specifically, but more than likely it will be used on a Window's machine as that will probably be the primary target audience.